# php code is not fetching data from mysql database using wamp server

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I want to display a table from database in phpMyAdmin by putting the following conditions that in every different options in drop down menu it displays different table from database by pressing the button of search. But it is not doing so.

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p></p>
<form method="post" action="" >
   <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
   <p>From:</p>
   <select name="from">
     <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
     <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
     <option value="murree">Murree</option>
     <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
   </select>
<p>To:</p>
   <select name="To">
     <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
     <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
     <option value="murree">Murree</option>
     <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> 
</table>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

if(isset($_POST['from']) and isset($_POST['To'])) {
    $from = $_POST['from'] ;
    $to = $_POST['To'] ;
    $table = array($from, $to);

    switch ($table) {
        case array ("Islamabad", "Lahore") :
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM flights");
           echo "</flights>";      //table name is flights
           break;
        case array ("Islamabad", "Murree") :
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM isb to murree");
          echo "</isb to murree>";     //table name isb to murree
          ;
          break;
       case array ("Islamabad", "Muzaffarabad") :
           $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM isb to muzz");
           echo "</isb to muzz>";
           break;
       //.....
       //......
       default:
          echo "Your choice is nor valid !!";
    }

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: User of root, with blank password only works in the console, unless I'm mistaken.  For PHP you will need a user other than root with an actual password.

Comment: @developerwjk, PHP works fine with root and blank password. This is a little mistake.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the log?

Comment: are you sure that query is correct? SELECT * FROM isb to muzz don't you missed a where clause?

Comment: @Alejo_Blue Check the comments, they seem to be table names :)

Comment: By the way, apart from my answer, you are currently outputting invalid html closing tags. That's not going to work very well either.

Comment: no error just displaying the same page in browser @Jay Blanchard

Comment: **I think a quick squint at the PHP manual would be the best idea**. `mysqli_query()` issues a query to MySQL, which runs that query and creates a result set. It is then up to you to process that result set using other mysqli_* commands. You dont appear to be processing the result set in any way at all. Which would explain why you are getting not data added to your page.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the current problem you are having is caused by your table names. When they contain spaces (or are reserved words, start with numbers, etc.), they need to be quoted in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `isb to murree`
```

However, I would probably take a good look at the database structure (and table names...) before I would go on because having a different table for each combination of destinations doesn't scale very well. All your combinations could easily be stored in one table (using just numbers to identify the airports) with perhaps some additional columns for additional information.

Comment: i cannot post image but yess i have tables with the same names. can you tell me where to insert name of database?? and my logic for connecting it with database is correct?? because it shows the same page not giving any error in browser..thanx @jeroen

Comment: @john I'm not sure what you mean, the 4th argument of `mysqli_connect()` should be the name of your database. Except for the missing backticks, the db-logic seems correct.

Comment: this echo "</isb to murree>"; is correct for showing table from db??@jeroen